# Setting a bit in data structure

Tags: c, memory, typedef

after a good amount of looking I could not find another post related to my problem.

I have a pretty big memory map in my program and I store data in memory according to the offset of the object.

At offset 4262, I have this struct which is a total of 1 byte:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char KCE_OPTION:1;
    unsigned char REMOTE_SECURITY_OPTION:1;
    unsigned char REMOTE_SEC_SWITCH_STAT:1;
    unsigned char FUTURE:5;
}ElevRemoteCtrlData;
```

In my main loop, I check to see if this position in memory has changed its value. I specifically look to see if:

```
oldVal->ElevRemoteCtrlData.REMOTE_SEC_SWITCH_STAT != newVal->ElevRemoteCtrlData.REMOTE_SEC_SWITCH_STAT
```

This condition does not pass even if I push a new value into this offset. I think the issue is that the specific bit I am looking at does not get changed? I either send 0x00 or 0x01 to that place in memory. (Only the MSB changes)

Can anyone please explain if it has anything to do with the order of members in my data struct. I am having trouble understanding who gets what bit.

Thanks for any help I can get.

Comment: `I either send 0x00 or 0x01 to that place in memory` - we need to see how you do that.

Comment: Im pointing to an address in an array and storing the data in it. I.e 'memoryOffset[i] = *data'